# How to Create Excel 2010 Scatter Chart with Text Values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have absolutely no Excel ability and would appreciate if someone could tell me how to create a particular chart.

I have created some data where I have rows for items with a text description and columns for 1 to 7.  I would like to plot on a chart only when one of the cells within the matrix has a value.

There is nothing numeric about this data.

An example of what I would like is this:

```
Item A         x        x

Item B      x      x  x

Item C                x  x 

Item D       x  x  x
       1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

I tried using a scatter chart but I got very strange results with numeric values.

Thanks

Comment: You can't do it. What about a pivot table?

Comment: I'm happy to use any kind of chart that looks like my example if you can help?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this-but not directly.  Excel cannot plot "letters" in a scatter (xy) chart.  However, it is easy to get around this limitation by assigning a numeric value to each letter/non-numeric value you want plotted.

So, in you example, add a column and fill it with values where A=1, B=2, C=3, D=4 and then use the numeric value for your Y (vertical) values.

Your chart would then match your example:

[image: xy_letters]

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2007/2010? Click on your chart and run the macro:

```
Sub Macro()
Dim serie As Series
Dim punto As Point
Dim columnStr As String
Dim column As Integer

columnStr = "C" ' Column with the names


column = Asc(UCase(columnStr)) - 64
Set serie = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1) ' Get chart
For Each punto In serie.Points
    pointRow = Val(Mid$(punto.Name, InStr(punto.Name, "P") + 1, 10)) ' Extract table row from point name
    Debug.Print punto.Name, pointRow
    punto.ApplyDataLabels ' Show label
    punto.DataLabel.Formula = "=Foglio1!R" & LTrim(Str(pointRow)) & "C" & LTrim(Str(column)) ' Assign label (change "Foglio" to your language )
Next
   
End Sub
```